# Why does not SqlConnectionFactory work with LocalDb?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, localdb

I know about `LocalDbConnectionFactory` but I'm interested why using `SqlConnectionFactory` with  the string

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

causes `System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException` to be thrown.

Comment: I think you should install SQLExpress.

Answer (score 0):

SqlConnectionFactory is probably geared towards SQL Express and can't deal with LocalDB, which is why they added the LocalDbConnectionFactory.

Is there some reason you can't just use the LocalDbConnectionFactory?

Comment: No reason, just want to know why. I thought LocalDB is absolutely the same sql express. At least it's what I got from docs.

Comment: They are not the same, from the SQL Server Express guys [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) looks like Express will probably be going away in time.